# CSS - Changing button colours?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, button

I am setting a look for all of my buttons by using the following code:

```
input[type=submit] {
font-family: Modern, serif;
border: none;
margin-right: 1em;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
background: #549396;
color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
position: relative;
}
```

The problem is all my buttons are the same, I want to be able to call certain buttons and change the look of them. For example a blue follow button and a grey unfollow button. Thanks guys

Comment: Not that you shouldn't make your own cool buttons, but why not use an existing library like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/)? Among many things it has pre-styled buttons in all sorts of shapes, sizes, and colors.

Comment: What is the problem with the most obvious approach of setting `color` and/or `background` properties (or some other) on some elements? If you mean how to use selectors to refer to them, then it is all up to your markup and whether you can change it by adding `class` or `id` attribites.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do seems to be a "hack". You have many buttons that have the same HTML and you want just to change some of them?

Having in mind that you are using forms... then you have a **form name**.

You can use this **CSS**:

```
form[name=login] input[type=submit]
{
    background: green;
}

form[name=subscribe] input[type=submit]
{
    background: red;
}
```

I'm assuming your forms have a name.

Comment: what the OP is asking for is not at all a hack, and considering CSS can be re-used there is no reason to scope them under their respective form names. That's only adding unnecessary code. Adding a simple class to override the original `background` color is sufficient

Comment: Yes, what you say it's the best choice, just adding a class for special styling like .red .big .lite whatever. But the question is not THAT clear. I would require @Divergent to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="blueBtn" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="grayBtn" />
```

You can just style each class and add them to your button but you shouldn't have more than one input type="submit" in a single form. You might want to change them to input type="button".

Is this what you want?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinli/8whho7gs/)

Answer (score 0):

can you add classes? just tack on a different class:

```
input[type=submit] {
  font-family: Modern, serif;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #549396;
  color: white;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=submit].red{
   background: red;
}

input[type=submit].green{
   background: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="red"/>
<input type="submit" class="green"/>
```